# Refer to a figure/table

Tags: hyperref, ref

I set up a label with \label{fig:f1}
Now i want to be the ref "figure 1"

How do i do that?

With varioref it is "1 on the next page"
And actually with hyperref "1"

Comment: Did you try with `cleveref` (to be loaded *after* `hyperref`)?

Comment: cleveref not found

Comment: \usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

Comment: ah now it's installed

Comment: So how do i call it now? I gued undefined control sequence for vref

Comment: Use `\cref{fig:f1}`, or `\Cref{fig:f1}` if it is the first word of a new sentence. Note you may group several references. Also, it can be customised (for your language, for instance).

Comment: Well now it is fig.

Comment: how do i config it to german?

Comment: got it now thanks

Comment: Load the `german` option of babel with the document class.

Comment: can i use it in beamer? I embed that but it does not show me the ref just Abb. 3

Comment: I don't know. Beamer has its own way to manage several kinds of environments.

Comment: okey thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote,

> I set up a label with `\label{fig:f1}`. Now i want to be the ref "figure 1"

You have two main options:

- Load the `hyperref` package and write

  ```
  \autoref{fig:f1}
  ```
- Load the `cleveref` package with the option `noabbrev` and write

  ```
  \cref{fig:f1}
  ```

  If you want the name of the object (here: "figure") to be part of the hyperlink, be sure to (a) load `cleveref` *after* `hyperref` and (b) load `cleveref` with the option `nameinlink`.

If, in addition, you want the name of the cross-referenced object to say "Abbildung" instead of "figure", load the `babel` package with the option `ngerman`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[b]\caption{A figure}\label{fig:f1}\end{figure}
\autoref{fig:f1}, \cref{fig:f1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand `hyperref` but never mind.

I assume that you know if you are referring to a figure, then why not:

```
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{figure \ref{#1}}
 ...
\fref{fig:f1}
```

Or for tables

```
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{table \ref{#1}}
...
\tref{tab:t1}
```